# How to generate colorful images using GDAL?

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am using `gdal_translate -of JPEG -scale -co worldfile=yes ndvi.tiff output.jpg` command to convert tiff images to jpg and resize it. But it generates only black and white images.

How can I generate colorful images when converting from tiff to jpg/jpeg?

Comment: what do you see when you run gdal_info on the file?

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll find you need to add `-expand rgb` to your command line, for example:

> gdal_translate -expand rgb -of JPEG input.tif output.jpg -co
>   WORLDFILE=YES

Nick.

Comment: I tried your given commmand. but it does not provide any uutput rather shows "Option -expand incomplete, or not recognised"
how to overcome this problem?

Comment: This is strange, it works here. If you copied the command line from here and pasted it into a command window there might be a font encoding problem. Try typing the command line rather than copying and pasting. Nick.

Comment: i typed it but yet no luck for me. is there any other reason or do i need to install some packages or so?

Comment: Okay, try running gdal_translate from within QGIS (Raster -> Conversion -> Translate). Tick 'Expand' and select 'RGB'. I can't understand why this isn't working from the command line, most odd. Nick.

Comment: i run the next commadn "gdal_translate -expand rgb  -of JPEG -scale -co worldfile=yes ndvi.tiff output.jpg" and it gives Input file size is 4087, 2176
Error : band 1 has no color table
any suggestion

Comment: Are you sure that the TIFF is really an image? Could you tell us a little more about what it is and where it came from. Nick.

Comment: yes, tiff is an image format. I generate it from modis data.

Comment: But not all TIFFs are images. Is it possible to put the TIFF in a place where it could be downloaded? Nick.

Comment: may be, but I am working wiht TIFF images

Answer (score 1):

you should use pct2rgb.py script for converting an 8bit paletted image to 24bit RGB.

Usage:

```
pct2rgb.py [-of format] [-b band] [-rgba] source_file dest_file
```

you can find script [here](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/pct2rgb.py). and some information [here](http://www.gdal.org/pct2rgb.html).

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Resize images with GDAL? Did you try to convert **TIFF to ECW**?

```
gdal_translate -of ECW -co TARGET=0 -expand rgb -a_srs EPSG:4326 input.tif output.ecw
```

Comment: no, i need to convert from tiff to jpg/jpeg